# How do we trace over subregions in a fermionic QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, quantum-information, fermions, grassmann-numbers

### Bosonic Case

In a bosonic QFT, the Hilbert space associated to a surface $\Sigma$ is the appropriate space of wavefunctionals on $\Sigma$. Hence, if $\Sigma=\Sigma_1 \sqcup \Sigma_2$, we find that the Hilbert space naturally decomposes as $\mathcal{H}_\Sigma = \mathcal{H}_{\Sigma_1} \otimes \mathcal{H}_{\Sigma_2}$ (ignoring any edge effects). Then field operators on $\Sigma_i$ can only act nontrivially on $\mathcal{H}_{\Sigma_i}$.

Given an overall state $\rho_\Sigma$, we can use this tensor product structure to trace out in the usual way, obtaining the reduced states $\rho_{\Sigma_1}$ and $\rho_{\Sigma_2}$. These reduced states give correct expectation values of operators localised to their portion of $\Sigma$. More concretely, for any $\mathcal{O}$ built from field operators on $\Sigma_1$, we have tr$(\rho_\Sigma \mathcal{O})=$ tr$((\rho_{\Sigma_1}\otimes \text{id}) \mathcal{O})$. We could even use this property to *define* the reduced states. But note: we'd still need the underlying tensor product structure in order to show that such a $\rho_{\Sigma_1}$ in fact exists with the desired property.

Finally, to actually compute these reduced states, we can perform path integrals over a "bra" and a "ket" spacetime (often Euclidean), glued along the region we wish to trace over.

In summary, bosonic QFT gives us a neat way to associate degrees of freedom to a spatial subregion, and allows us to "forget about" or "trace over" those degrees of freedom.

### Fermionic Case

In a fermionic QFT, things don't seem to work so simply. It can't be the case that a field operator on $\Sigma_i$ only acts nontrivially on a tensor product factor $\mathcal{H}_{\Sigma_i}$, because that would mean spacelike separated operators would commute, when of course really they should anticommute.

I suppose this doesn't mean we have to throw out the tensor product structure entirely. But it does mean that field operators don't "play nicely" with the tensor product structure. How, then, can we talk about tracing out? Do there still exist reduced states giving correct expectation values for field operators localised to subregions? If so, is there a path integral representation of these reduced states?

And if it's the case that there's no equivalent "tracing out" procedure for fermions, how can we compute entropies?

Comment: The procedure works exactly the same way for fermions. You just need to accept the fact that tensor product of fermionic Hilbert spaces is  a bit different from the bosonic case, i.e. field operators acting on different places anti commute.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that tensor products and traces for vector spaces should be generalized to [super vector spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_vector_space) with appropriate [Koszul sign rule/convention](https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=koszul+sign), stemming from permuting Grassmann-odd objects.

In particular, space-like separated operators super-commute, i.e. their supercommutator vanishes.

References:

1. Bryce DeWitt, *Supermanifolds,* Cambridge Univ. Press, 1992.